# Bash wildcard expansion (2)

Tags: bash, wildcard

I'm sorry if this is too simple or has been covered before... but I hope someone here can help out. I can't figure out how to expand the * wildcard in a pathname unless it is followed by a space.  For example,

```
echo $path* $dir
```

yields

```
/Data0001 /subfolder
```

which is what I want, but without the space. If I try to take out the space with,

```
echo $path*$dir
```

I get,

```
/Data*/subfolder
```

Any tips on how to get the * to expand without the whitespace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Put the variable name(s) in curly braces, e.g.:

```
echo ${path}*${dir}
```

Comment: That still returns /Data*/subfolder

Answer (score 1):

It's doing pattern matching on the entire word, not just the `${path}*` part -- so if $path was "/" and $dir was "/subdirname", it would look for matches to `/*/subdirname`, which essentially looks for directories in / that contain subdirectories named subdirname. If you want it to find directories that don't already contain /subdirname, you have to leave that out of pattern, and add it later. Here's an example that stores the matches in an array, then adds the subdirectory:

```
path="/"
dir="/subdirname"
matchedDirs=("$path"*)
echo "${matchedDirs[@]/%/$dir}"
```

If that final construct is hard to make out, the `[@]` part means "all elements of the array, each treated as a separate word", and `/%/$dir` means "replace the end (of each element) with $dir" (i.e. append $dir to each array element).

Comment: With my setup I only expect `path*` to match one directory, but still this does the job.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! Since it did the job, please [mark it as the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
dir=/Data sub=subfolder
echo $dir*/$sub
```

.

```
dir=/Data* sub=subfolder
echo $dir/$sub
```

would also work